# fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'

Tags: facebook-like, integration, app-id, secret-key

Facebook debugger says: "Object at URL 'http://www.domain.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '1234567890' for property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid',

It worked fine already, but now the buttons don't appear anymore. The shop was just offline for one day. I loaded the data again, but no change.

Comment: And you're sure the app ID in use is a real app ID and isn't disabled/deleted/in sandbox mode?